# get CustomAttribute Value "No" in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom-attributes

I have create custom attribute for product, I  try to get productCollection via, its throwing some value **NO**

**What I did:**

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

    class RelativeProduct
    {

        protected $_productCollectionFactory;

        protected $storeManager;
         protected $_objectManager;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
        {
            $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
            $this->storeManager =$storeManager;
             $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        }

        public function execute()
        {   
            $storeID = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
            $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeID);
            $currentStoreID = $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());
            echo $currentStoreID;

            $collections = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(array('*'))->load();

            foreach ($collections as $product) {
               echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
               echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
               echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->setStoreId(1)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
               echo " 1 ";
               echo  $product->getAttributeText('brand');
               echo " 2 ";
               echo $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'brand',$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
               echo " 3 ";
               echo "  ";
           exit();


        }

    }
```

If I tried:

```
               echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
               echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
               echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->setStoreId(1)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

It throws: No Value.

If I use:

```
echo $product->getAttributeText('brand');
```

```
echo $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'brand', $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```

This doesn't get any value.

But, Each product have this custom attribute value.

Suggest Me how to get Custom Attribute value.

Comment: What type of attribute is this?

Comment: @harri Dropdown  field

Comment: Check your attribute settings `Storefront Properties -> Used Product Listing` must be `Yes`.

Comment: @magentotwo Yes I set  `Used in Product Listing` value `Yes`

Comment: @Rajkumar.E now flush the cache and try again.

Comment: @magentotwo I tried, reindex, static-content, clear cache, same issue, But some  select attribute only issue not all.